# How implement location search (and item search by location)?

Tags: java, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I need to implement location search and search by location (the best examples are **booking.com**, or **airbnb**)

In a nutshell:

1. users can create some items related to cities (like hotels in a city), so they need to be able searching cities by names, to put it in items;
2. then users can search created items by city, country, region, continent etc...for example all items in Paris, or all items in France, or all items in Europe.
3. location search should support multiple languages.

I think, that is the quite standard problem, but to my shame I have no strong idea how to implement this (my application based on Java, Spring, MySQL, Angular).

Firstly I thought about using Google places API for the 1. task: type city name on UI, receive the list of matched cities, get **name, latitude and longitude** for each item, save it. But I don't exactly know how to solve searching items by aggregated locations (e.g. by country). Using coordinates solves multilingual support. But are country coordinates return by Places API correct (I think no)? Is MySQL spatial indices enough for it?

Or may be I should compose hierarchical name for each city like **paris** - **Ile de france** - **france** and search by LIKE? But how support multiple languages efficiently in that case?

Or may be I should compose hierachical chain of ids **paris_id** + **Ile de france id** + **france id**?

May be instead of using Google API I need to keep my own location database (for example based on GeoNames) ?

Any suggestions how to solve my problem efficiently are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a hybrid approach.

- use state/region/city codes for filtering
- use neighbors (like
  [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/how-to-best-implement-nearest-neighbour-search-in-mysql#4556)) for distance-based search